# How do you pass an attribute value to the has_many through join table with FactoryGirl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot

food.rb factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :food do
    factory :apple do
      description 'apple'
      sequence(:name) { |n| "apple #{n}"}
      long_description 'Apple'
    end

    factory :burger do
      description 'burger'
      sequence(:name) { |n| "burger #{n}"}
      long_description 'Burger'
    end

    after(:create) do |food|
      [:fat, :protein, :carb, :fiber].each do |nutrient|
        food.nutrients << FactoryGirl.create(nutrient, :measurement)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

nutrient.rb factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :nutrient do
    factory :fat do
      name 'Fat'
      slug 'fat'
    end

    factory :protein do
      name 'Protein'
      slug 'protein'
    end

    factory :carb do
      name 'Carbohydrates'
      slug 'carbohydrates'
    end

    factory :fiber do
      name 'Fiber'
      slug 'fiber'
    end

    trait :measurement do
      measurement 'milligrams'
    end
  end
end
```

food_nutrient.rb factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :food_nutrient do
    food
    nutrient
    qty rand(1..100)
  end
end
```

Feature test:

```
feature 'Search' do
  scenario 'for apples' do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    apples  = 15.times.map { FactoryGirl.create(:apple) }
    burgers = 5.times.map { FactoryGirl.create(:burger) }

    ...more code
  end
end
```

The error I get is: 
Failure/Error: apples  = 15.times.map { FactoryGirl.create(:apple) }
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Qty can't be blank

Qty is an attribute in the food_nutrient has_many :through join_table.  How do I pass in that variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add `FoodNutrient` instances in your `after(:create)` rather than adding nutrients directly:

```
after(:create) do |food|
  [:fat, :protein, :carb, :fiber].each do |nutrient|
    food.food_nutrients << FactoryGirl.create(:food_nutrient, 
      nutrient: FactoryGirl.create(:nutrient, :measurement)
    )
  end
end
```

This will then use your `food_nutrient` factory to create the `FoodNutrient` instance associated with each of the four nutrients.

Comment: Seems so simple once you see it.  All I could think of is "well that's obvious".  I'm assuming you pass in the food object and the qty attribute, correct?  Could you update?

Comment: You *can* pass in the food and the quantity if you want to but they have default values from your factory definition (of a newly created Food instance and 'milligrams' respectively).